# Clicking div and making another one disappear

Tags: jquery

When I press one div, another div's opacity should be set to `0`. My code is not working so I'm hoping for help. Thanks to anyone who helps.

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#box1').fadeTo("slow", 0);
});
```

```html
<div id="container3">
    <div id="button1"></div>
    <div id="box1"></div>
</div>
```

```css
#box1 {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 200px;
    background-color: green;
}

#button1 {
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    right: 100px;
}

#container3 {
    width: 1955px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1955px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/o3xx7b7p/. Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I guess click event not bound. Set it once element is inside DOM or wrap it in document ready handler

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the correct signature `.fadeTo(opacity,"speed")`,

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#box1').fadeTo(0, "slow");
});
```

Your code is working fine. Problem must be somewhere else.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/woc6o12b/)

Comment: The right signature is `.fadeTo( duration, opacity [, complete ] )`

Comment: @A.Wolff Is it? Just got confused. will delete it now.

Comment: Guys, could not delete the answer now as I have deleted 5 answers today during clean up. Will delete it for sure when system permits.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to anyone who helped.
the problem was that i didmt put:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

If anyone could explain why it would be lovely, Thanks.